# cannot update row value for integer column in postgresql table

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

This is the dummy function I wrote to update the counter.

```
def updateTable(tableName, visitorId, dtWithZone):
    db_uri = app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"]
    engine = create_engine(db_uri, connect_args={"options": "-c timezone={}".format(dtWithZone.timetz().tzinfo.zone)})

    # create session
    Session = sessionmaker()
    Session.configure(bind=engine)
    session = Session()

    meta = MetaData(engine, reflect=True)
    table = meta.tables[tableName]
    print dir(table)
    # update row to database
    row = session.query(table).filter(
          table.c.visitorId == visitorId).first()
    print 'original:', row.count
    row.count = row.count + 1
    print "updated {}".format(row.count)
    session.commit()
    conn.close()
```

but when it reaches the line `row.count = row.count + 1` it throws error:

```
AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

this is the table

```
 \d visitorinfo;
             Table "public.visitorinfo"
    Column    |           Type           | Modifiers 
--------------+--------------------------+-----------
 platform     | character varying(15)    | 
 browser      | character varying(10)    | 
 visitorId    | character varying(10)    | not null
 language     | character varying(10)    | 
 version      | character varying(20)    | 
 cl_lat       | double precision         | 
 cl_lng       | double precision         | 
 count        | integer                  | 
 ip           | character varying(20)    | 
 visitor_time | timestamp with time zone | 
Indexes:
    "visitorinfo_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree ("visitorId")
```

what am I doing wrong ?why is it saying cannot set attribute?

part of updated code:

```
# update row to database
row = session.query(table).filter(
      table.c.visitorId == visitorId).first()
print 'original:', row.count
val = row.count
row.count = val + 1
print "updated {}".format(row.count)
```

Comment: row.count seems only to be a get-able property. Put it in a variable first. then you can add 1 to it.

Comment: @AlexT82 : no dude that didnt worked :(

Comment: really, it will. make a new variable, call it rowCount. then put row.Count into it, and you'll be able to also increase it by one

Comment: thats what I did but it didn't worked.

Comment: can you show the updated the code sample with that?

Comment: @AlexT82 : have a  look at part of updated code

Comment: row.count = val + 1 should be:  val = val + 1, and then use val in the print update....

Comment: then if I set row.count to updated val will throw the same error.

Comment: of course; you CANNOT SET the row.count property. That's an ATTRIBUTE (which cannot be set by code; it's automatically calculated based on the underlying object.)

Comment: well than how should I update that value of the underlying object.

Comment: You're working with Core objects. Your `table` is a `Table` instance, not a mapped class (read ORM). Query results are thus keyed tuples, not model objects. A tuple is immutable. Use `Query.update()` and the like (look it up from SQLA Query API docs).

Answer (score 0):

use an update query:

```
UPDATE public.visitorinfo SET counter = counter + 1 WHERE visitorId = 'VisitorID'
```

Make sure that last 'VisitorID' is filled from your application

Comment: I tried this `UPDATE visitorinfo SET count='10' WHERE 'visitorId'='E1RH00NEJ';` but this isn't working

Comment: removing the where clause it works, `E1RH00NEJ` definitely exists.

Comment: Why did you use single quotes for column name? You should either use double quotes (if it indeed is visitorId and not visitorid) or don't use quotes at all.